# morris js y values big difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I have a problem with morris js, im plotting 2 lines with the first y values are between 50 and 500 and the secound y value are between 0 - 10.

The problem is that the difference is to big and the plotting becomes wierd i that sense there is a huge gap in the diagram.

Here is a picture of what i mean, its hard to explain. You can see the gap between those two plots in the image below.

[image]

Here is the code.

```
Morris.Line({
          element: 'goalChart',
          data: data,
          xkey: 'y',
          ykeys: ['a', 'c'],
          labels: ['Klick', 'CTR'],
          resize: true,
          ymax: 'auto',
          axes: 'x',
          pointSize: 3,
          eventLineColors:[$.colors("yellow", 600)],
          smooth: true,
          gridTextColor: '#474e54',
          gridLineColor: '#eef0f2',
          goalLineColors: '#e3e6ea',
          gridTextFamily: $.configs.get('site', 'fontFamily'),
          gridTextWeight: '300',
          numLines: 7,
          gridtextSize: 14,
          lineWidth: 1,
          lineColors: [$.colors("green", 600), $.colors("primary", 600)]
        });
```

Comment: You should really provide MCVE regarding this kind of question

Comment: Sorry was not familiar with that term, is this better @A.Wolff ?